# Change number's color based on if-else condition using python

Tags: python

I am a novice programmer and I have created this code so that the number changes color depending on the average, but the colors are changing randomly.

```
   import random
    from termcolor import colored , cprint
    my_list = []
    
    
    for i in range(0,10):
        numbers = random.randint(1,10)
        max_student = max(1, i) #only necessary if we want the person to enter the range of students
        my_list.append(numbers)
        sum1 = sum(my_list)
        average = sum1/max_student   
        if average >= my_list[i] :
            cprint(my_list[i], "green")
        elif average < my_list[i]:
            cprint(my_list[i], "red")
     
    print(" this is the average : ", round(average, 2))
```

Comment: What are your expectation?

Comment: What do you mean *"the colors are changing randomly"*? They change according to the criteria you defined in your code. Maybe you defined it wrong. But we can't help if you don't ***explain*** what that criteria is (in other words, post expected output). After all, you can't expect us to understand what the code is supposed to do if your code is wrong...

Comment: Please read about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to run your code line-by-line. Lastly, after debugging your code, create a [mre] of a ***specific*** problem you found in the process and ask about that

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the code is average is changing during each iteration in for loop.
and you are comparing your result with average we got after the loop.
you need to get average and my_list in one for loop and compare the value in another loop .

```py
import random
from termcolor import colored , cprint
my_list = []
    
    
for i in range(0,10):
    numbers = random.randint(1,10)
    max_student = max(1, i) #only necessary if we want the person to enter the range of students
    my_list.append(numbers)
    sum1 = sum(my_list)
    average = sum1/max_student


for i in range(0,10):
    if average >= my_list[i] :
        cprint(my_list[i], "green")
    elif average < my_list[i]:
        cprint(my_list[i], "red")    

print(" this is the average : ", round(average, 2))
```

Comment: You are still calculating the average ***inside*** the loop...